# Qt3DWindow: add entities to root entity after initialization

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt3d, pyside2

Is it possible to add `QEntity` objects to root entity of `Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow` after this `Qt3DWindow`has been initialized?

At the moment my code does not work. It crashes when I call the method `add_entity`.

```py
class Window(Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.camera().lens().setPerspectiveProjection(90, 1, .1, 5000)
        self.root_entity = Qt3DCore.QEntity()

        self.axes = Axes(self.root_entity)
        self.text = None

    def add_entity(self):
        self.text = Text(self.root_entity)
```

Comment: It should be possible. What is your Text class? What is the error message?

Comment: @HappyFeet: Usually something like this: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.

Comment: What happens when you add it in the init method?

Comment: It works when I add it in `__init__` method.